# Tab Styles Inspiration not working properly with 4 tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

hello i got Tab Styles Inspiration from [Codrope][1]

but every tab has 5 tabs and it working fine but whenever i am trying to delete 5 one and keep 4 tabs as my requirement so dragging bottom border not working!

Please can anyone give me the best solution for my tabs that how i can keep for tabs

here is my source like please it live

```html
<a href="http://codepen.io/fazurrehman/pen/ONRmwN">See here my demo on codepen.io</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem you having is in the `css` on the `Move the line`

before:

```
/* Move the line */
.tabs-style-linemove nav li:first-child.tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-400%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-400%,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li:nth-child(2).tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li:nth-child(3).tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-200%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-200%,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li:nth-child(4).tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}
```

after:

```
/* Move the line */
.tabs-style-linemove nav li:first-child.tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li:nth-child(2).tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-200%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-200%,0,0);
}

.tabs-style-linemove nav li:nth-child(3).tab-current ~ li:last-child::before {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much! I was trying to find solution in JS file